# CSS style not applied when comes from an imported CSS file

Tags: css, angular, sass

I defined some CSS at the component level (my-component.scss)

```
@import '../../../../../theme';

app-page-content {

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;

  div {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
      .mat-form-field-infix {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
    }

    ::ng-deep .mat-radio-label-content,
    .mat-list-text,
    ::ng-deep .mat-select-value,
    .mat-input-element {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    ::ng-deep mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
      background-color: mat-color($palette-primary);
    }

    .mat-list-base .mat-list-item,
    .mat-list-base .mat-list-option {
      height: 30px !important;
    }

    mat-form-field {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    mat-radio-group {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    mat-radio-button {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .file-uploader {
      margin-bottom: 40px !important;
      display: block;
    }

    .file-uploader button {
      background-color: #444;
    }

    .upload-progress {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

  }

}
```

As I want to use this style for various components (and I'm not allowed to insert style into style.scss), I created a new file *"cms.scss"*, where I moved the *app-page-content* part.

Now *my-component.scss* looks like that

```
@import '../../../../../theme';
@import url('../../style/cms.scss');
```

And *cms.scss*

```
app-page-content {

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;

  div {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-legacy {
      .mat-form-field-infix {
        border: 0 !important;
      }
    }

    ::ng-deep .mat-radio-label-content,
    .mat-list-text,
    ::ng-deep .mat-select-value,
    .mat-input-element {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    ::ng-deep mat-list-option[aria-selected="true"] .mat-pseudo-checkbox {
      background-color: mat-color($palette-primary);
    }

    .mat-list-base .mat-list-item,
    .mat-list-base .mat-list-option {
      height: 30px !important;
    }

    mat-form-field {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    mat-radio-group {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    mat-radio-button {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .file-uploader {
      margin-bottom: 40px !important;
      display: block;
    }

    .file-uploader button {
      background-color: #444;
    }

    .upload-progress {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

  }

}
```

Unfortunately the style is now more applied, as it's completely ignored by the browser.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why don't you import it into your `styleUrls` array, in your component decorator ? And why are you using `url(...)` while you don't use it just the line above ?

Comment: It's fine to use url (...), but for consistency in formatting, I suggest you to better stick to one format, as what pointed out by @trichetriche.

Comment: @trichetriche, I forgot `styleUrls` option. About the `url(...)` stuff, I just copy-pasted some code, this is why. Let me try the `styleUrls` way

Comment: @tnkh even if it's fine, it's 10 more characters for the same result ... And it's not the recommended way to import files in SASS !

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @trichetriche, I imported *cms.scss* directly from the component decorator.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../style/cms.scss']
})
```

This way there is no problem.